# compare a string with lines and remove the line which contains words

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a txt file contains:

```
127.0.0.1    test69.com
127.0.0.1    http://test69.com
127.0.0.1      ok.tk
127.0.0.1 man.test
```

If I have the strings: `test69.com` and `man.test` to compare with this file , how could the c# program remove the line (1)(2)(4) in file?

Comment: Take a look at [string.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string[] domains = { "test69.com", "man.test" };
string[] lines = File.ReadLines(fileName)
                     .Where(l => !domains.Any(d => l.Contains(d)))
                     .ToArray();

// write lines basck to file, if you need
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines);
```

Comment: You don't need `ToArray()` since 4.0, do you?

Comment: @KingKing I prefer `ReadLines` to avoid creation of another array with all lines

Comment: @KingKing: `ReadLines()` is deferred and [exists since 4.0+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). `ReadAllLines` is not and [exists since 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: @abatishchev really? I'm a little lagging behind with new stuff in new version of .NET :)

Comment: @abatishchev yep, I know there is `WriteAllLines` which accepts enumerable, but in this case I'm writing back to same file, which will be in use, if I'll keep enumerable result :)

Comment: Actually it didn't work, the file has been written contains many miscellaneous unwanted characters

Comment: @NguyễnNgọcTuyền maybe you are looking on other file. With this code your sample file will contain exactly one string `127.0.0.1      ok.tk`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Dear Mr lazyberezovsky. If I have 2 selected items in a listbox eg: 1st line: test69.com ; 2nd line: man.test. How can I find 2 strings in file and replace like the way you show me. My first question is done perfectly by you, thanks for advanced

Comment: @NguyễnNgọcTuyền create string array or list from your selected items (same as I created `domain` array) and use it to remove lines which contain any of items. Or you want some other kind of replacement?

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = @"C:\datafile.txt";
    string [] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    List<string> newlines = new List<string>();

   foreach (string line in allLines)
   {
       if (!line.Contains("test69.com") && !line.Contains("http://test69.com") && !line.Contains("man.test"))           
           newlines.Add(line);              
    }    
   File.WriteAllLines(path, newlines.ToArray());     
}
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to do not use `List<string>`, using `yield return` instead. And as twice as more efficient to do not call `ToArray()`.