# Filter and load string to a listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a txt file contains:

```
#
#test
this is a test
127.0.0.1    test69.com
127.0.0.1    http://test69.com
127.0.0.1    www.test69.com
127.0.0.1    man.test
127.0.0.1    http://man.test
127.0.0.1    www.man.test
127.0.0.1    www.another.test
```

How can I load all the lines in to a listbox but just keep only 3 lines in listbox like :

```
test69.com
man.test
another.test
```

Example: My code works well but I can't avoid that my listbox loaded `www.test69.com` and `http://test69.com` but I don't want them, I just want something like `test69.com` appears

```
string str = "";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\GhoSter\\Desktop\\test.txt");
        while ((str = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (Check(str) == true)
            {
                string localip = str.Substring(0,9);
                string load = str.Replace(localip + "   ", "");
                myList.Add(load);
            }
        }
        this.listBox1.DataSource = myList;
    }

    bool Check(string s)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        if (s == "" || s == null)
            flag = false;
        else
        {
            string first = s.Substring(0, 1);
            switch (first)
            {
                case "0":
                case "1":
                case "2":
                case "3":
                case "4":
                case "5":
                case "6":
                case "7":
                case "8":
                case "9":
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    flag = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Comment: Last today question, huh?

Comment: What have you tried for yourself? What is not working in the code that you have written? Any errors? Any exceptions?

Comment: you want distinct names without "www" & ip addres from all lines in a text file right ?

Comment: [compare a string with lines and remove the line which contains words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344023/compare-a-string-with-lines-and-remove-the-line-which-contains-words), [storage selected listbox items into a new array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350155/storage-selected-listbox-items-into-a-new-array)... seems you let others to do your work for you?

Comment: @PhoenixReborn: I can't avoid that things my listbox load `www.test69.com` and `http://test69.com` but I don't want them, I just want something like `test69.com` appears

Comment: How many time you have changed you question !!!!!

Comment: Well that is fine. Since we cannot possibly know by what arbitrary rule you decide which strings that you want to include and which you do not, how do you suppose that we would know? Besides that, you have not shown any effort to do your own work, yet.

Comment: so post you  code to help  you

Comment: @JulieShannon: I just explain more clearly than what I wanna say at first

Comment: ok post your code is the best way to provide you the right solution

Comment: @JulieShannon and PhoenixReborn
I knew, but my code is not short, I'm still a new member and don't know how to post the question for the best scientifically.

Comment: So it's ok. Please forgive me the amateur

Comment: @Tuyen Nguyen my answer updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I guess you want distinct names without "www" & ip addres from all lines in a text file**

note :- if wrong please comment about requirement still clear.This is just to filter the string.Rest you do for the Listbox as per your logic.

Try this code

```
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\fil.txt");

        int ctr = 0;

        foreach (var item in lines)
        {
            string tmp = item;

            tmp = tmp.Replace("127.0.0.1", "");
            tmp = tmp.Replace("http://", "");
            tmp = tmp.Replace("www.", "");
            tmp = tmp.Trim();

            if (ctr < lines.Length)
            {
                lines[ctr] = tmp;
                ctr++;
            }

        }

        //to skip initial lines
        var result = lines.Skip(3).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `Uri` class to parse and validate it and to remove the protocol. Then use `Enumerable.Distinct` to remove duplicates:

```
var listOfDistinctUrls = File.ReadLines(@"PathToTextFile");
    .Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l))
    .Select(l => {
        string token = l.Split().Last();
        Uri uri;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(token, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out uri))
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(uri.IsAbsoluteUri ? uri.Host + uri.PathAndQuery : uri.ToString());
            int wwwIndex = fileName.IndexOf("www.", 0, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            return wwwIndex >= 0 ? fileName.Substring(wwwIndex + 4) : fileName;
        }
        else
            return null;
    })
    .Where(u => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(u))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Result:

```
test69.com
man.test
```

Comment: Its great. can i debug the part inside linq ?

Comment: I'm trying your code, I'll give the feedback

Comment: @shan: You can debug the anonymous method in the `Select`, just set a breakpoint there. Normally you can't debug lambdas(e.g. here in the `Where`).

Answer (score 1):

here  how you can do this

```
string[] lines =File.ReadAllLines(yourpathFile);  
//in your listbox 
listBox1.Items.AddRange(lines.Take(6).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<string> arr = new List<string>();
StreamReader r = File.OpenText( Server.MapPath("b.txt"));
while (!r.EndOfStream)
{
   Match match = Regex.Match(r.ReadLine(), @"(www.|http://)([\w.]+)$");
   if (match.Success)
   {
     arr.Add(Regex.Replace(match.Value, @"(http://|www.)", ""));
   }
}
ListBox1.DataSource = arr.Distinct();
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Worked, thanks mr Samiey Mehdi, but it doesn't load any other single IP line

Comment: 'yeah, I think this is the best solution

Comment: @Tuyen Nguyen my answer updated